# Decltype of member functions

Tags: c++, function, member, decltype

```
class A {
    int f(int x, int j) { return 2;}
    decltype(f)* p;
};
```

Gives me the error:

```
error: decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function
```

I can't understand why that error is even speaking of overloaded functions. Similarly I thought that maybe I needed to use the scope operator to access the function:

```
class A {
    int f(int x, int j) { return 2;}
    decltype(A::f)* p;
};
```

Which still gives me an error but a clearer description:

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function 'int A::f(int, int)'
```

Why is it that I'm not allowed to use decltype to find the type of a member function? Alternatively setting the member function to `static` removes the error in either case.

Comment: what compiler and compiler version are you using?

Comment: @RichardChambers g++ 4.8.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you really want is:

```
struct a {
    int f(int x, int j) { return 2;}
    decltype(&a::f) p;
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b46d3520fc00aa42)

Since the `f` you are referring to is a member function. The deduced type is:

```
int(a::*)(int, int)
```

Without the `&` the compiler is assuming that you are trying to call the function without providing arguments to it. Perhaps Clang's error message is clearer about this:

> ```
> error: call to non-static member function without an object argument
>     decltype(a::f) p;
> ```

---

If you really don't want the pointer type you can later apply `std::remove_pointer_t` from `<type_traits>`.

Comment: "the compiler is assuming that you are trying to call the function without providing arguments to it." That's weird since it would not assume that if I passed decltype with the name of an ordinary function. Also I was not aware that the type of class members is preceded by a scope operator - what should I look up to understand that a bit better?

Comment: @Silversonic "Member function pointer" I guess. Remember that any non static member function needs to also have `this` "implicitly passed to it" so you can see a `Return(Class::*)(Arg1, Arg2, ...)` as `Return(Class* const, Arg1, Arg2, ...)` and that's why `Return(Class::*)(Arg1, Arg2, ...)` and `Return(*)(Arg1, Arg2, ...)` cannot possibly be the same type.